BLEDescriptor for Battery Service
I´m developing my first BLE device and need help.
I wonder if any kind person would like to help me. I want help with how to display a value in volts in the Battery Service function for BLA. I have tried the following code but get the unit volts in unit %. My wish is that my global variable ”uint8_t voltage” should be able to be sent to the mobile app and there show e.g.”Battery Voltage: 14.8V” The current code reads: ”Battery Voltage 14%”
I think I understand that in the function 3.5 Battery Energy Status it should be possible to add 3,5,1,3 Present Voltage field But I have no idea how to do it and I can't find any examples for this
This is my current code:
#define BatteryService BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x180F) 
BLECharacteristic BatteryLevelCharacteristic(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2A19), BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ | BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY);
BLEDescriptor BatteryLevelDescriptor(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2901));
BLECharacteristic BatteryVoltageCharacteristic(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2BF0), BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ | BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY);
BLEDescriptor BatteryVoltageDescriptor(BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x2901));

Otherwise, I have started from this example:
https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/esp32-ble-server-how-to-use-gatt-services-for-battery-level-indication
Mobile app
I've tried different UUIDs and Characteristics without getting it to work. I think I lack fundamental knowledge but would like to learn and understand how to do it.
Thanks in advance
Roger
